# syntax error after placing images in res/drawable directory

Tags: java, syntax-error, android-2.2-froyo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: drawable resource with numbers. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096892/android-drawable-resource-with-numbers-is-it-possible)

I'm creating an android application that includes images.

every couple of images contains the following naming convention:

```
001a.jpg
001b.jpg

002a.jpg
002b.jpg
...
```

since I coped the images to res/drawable directory
I got Syntax error for every image that I copied. I copied 40 images, so 40 syntax
error messages.

the syntax error message only contain the number of the image and not the all image name.
for example: instead of `001a.jpg` and `001b.jpg` i just see the following twice:

```
Syntax error on token: "001". delete this token
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources must follow a name pattern (in your case not  start with a number), because the file name is used as a java field name in `R`. So it must be a valid java identifier.