# Android Studio: underscores in literals are not supported error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, drawable, identifier, r.java-file

I have a problem with the drawable class in  R.java file. I had drawable hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi... folders in main/res, but drawable was missing so i created it by hand. Main.xml is able to find the image declared but this code in R.java gives an error:

```
    public static final class drawable {
    public static final int 10_device_access_accounts=0x7f020000;
    public static final int 10_device_access_add_alarm=0x7f020001;
    public static final int 10_device_access_alarms=0x7f020002;
    public static final int 10_device_access_battery=0x7f020003;
    public static final int 10_device_access_bightness_low=0x7f020004;
    public static final int 10_device_access_bluetooth=0x7f020005;
    public static final int 10_device_access_bluetooth_connected=0x7f020006;
    public static final int 10_device_access_bluetooth_searching=0x7f020007;
    public static final int 10_device_access_brightness_auto=0x7f020008;
    ...}
```

When compiled gives out an error: 
Gradle: error: underscores in literals are not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable underscores in literals)

I'm using android studio version 1.0.0.1 and jdk 1.7.0.250 version, i have PATH variable pointing to %JAVA_HOME%\bin and CLASSPATH pointing to %JAVA_HOME%\lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the "10_" at the beginning of your files can fix the issue. [For the reason why you can't have a resource with a numeric name, read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096892/android-drawable-resource-with-numbers-is-it-possible) . If theses drawable ressources are icons, you can use the common naming conventions that you can read [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#DesignTips), and begin your icons by "ic_" or "ic_menu" if this is Menu icons and Action Bar icons.

Comment: Yes, but won't that create another issue, since R.java file is auto-generated and should not be manually altered...

Comment: Ok, i figured it out, so the error was not with the icons i was using, but every drawable folder, so i just removed the number extension in the folders