# Unable to clear error "underscores in literals are not supported"

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-studio

I am working in Android Studio 0.8.9 and I am unable to clear the error "underscores in literals are not supported in source 1.6"

I have removed the image files that had underscores in their names, and tried syncing the gradel files and invalidating caches and restarting.  I deleted the r.java file as well, but it just keeps rebuilding it with references to those files.

Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio: underscores in literals are not supported error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702958/android-studio-underscores-in-literals-are-not-supported-error)

Comment: Nevermind, I found it!  The files were still in the app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4 folder, once I deleted them it built successfully.

Comment: in the future, a `gradle clean` seems like it would have helped in this situation. Or just completely deleting the `./build` directory (or renaming it if deleting makes you nervous). Most projects are setup so that folder can be deleted at any time with no adverse effects.